# Update GDAL library with R in Window

Tags: r, windows, gdal, rgdal

I have been trying to update my GDAL installation to the current version but I can't get R to recognize the updated libraries.

I ran the updater through OSGEO4W to get the new libraries.

From the command prompt I can see gdal has been updated

```
gdalinfo --version

    GDAL 3.1.4, released 2020/10/20
```

However, in R, even after reinstalling rgdal, it still shows the old version

```
> getGDALVersionInfo()
[1] "GDAL 3.0.4, released 2020/01/28"
```

How can I get R to work with the new gdal libraries?